# Snap to each list item when swiping on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a simple horizontal list that is swipeable on a mobile device. Once a tab is clicked on, its page content is displayed.

However, I would like to have the swiping SNAP from tab to tab. Once a tab is snapped to, that tab will then become active and show its page content.

In short, the goal is to swipe tab to tab, NOT swipe and click.

Does anyone have any code or resources they would like to share with me to achieve this effect?

Cheers.

PS: I only need to test for iOS

Comment: Can you share some sample code you've..? or do you just want *teh code?*

Answer (score 0):

You can use hammer js to do actual swipe. To slide between tabs you can use jquery scrollTo plugin passing an index of the tab you are swiping to. Because .eq method is zero-based index of the last tab would be tabs length - 1.

Every content section will have its index as well, so based on the tab's index you can show relevant content section.